# it is difficult to understand below typedef use case

Tags: c

Below typedef use case really confuses me, can you give an explaination for each line?

```
typedef char *one;
one abc();
typedef one (*twft)();
twft abcde();
```

Comment: The first line makes `one` into a synonym for `char *`.  The second line declares that `abc` is a function that takes an indeterminate argument list and returns a `one` (aka `char *`).  The third line defines `twft` as a pointer to a function that takes an indeterminate argument list and returns a `one` (aka `char *`).  The last line declares that `abcde` is a function that takes an indeterminate argument list and returns a `twft` — aka pointer to function of the specified type.

Comment: Note that there are no prototypes in the code shown.  You'd need `one abc(void);` and `typedef one (*twft)(void);` and `twft abcde(void);` or similar to create prototypes.  As it stands, all you know is that the functions do not take a variable argument list (are not declared or defined with `, ...` at the end of the argument list — are not variadic functions like `printf()` et al).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'one' is a typedef as char pointer

```
typedef char *one;
```

'abc' function declaration returning char pointer

```
one abc()
```

'twft' is typedef of a function pointer returning char pointer

```
typedef one (*twft)()
```

The last one is that function declaration of abcde() which returns a function pointer of a function defined by above typedef

```
twft abcde()
```